# Is it impossible to create GUI in python without tkinter?

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

I wanna know, Is it possible to create GUI in python without using tkinter?

Comment: There are other options, beginning with terminal-based "curses" and many external GUI libraries like PyQt, wxPython, kivy,...

Comment: You can try https://webui.me

Answer (score 0):

Tk isn't technically making the GUI, it's delegating to a C library; **and that's exactly what you can do too.** For simplicity however, it's pretty much standard to use TkInter, or some other framework (i recommend [PySimpleGUI](https://pysimplegui.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)) that takes care of the Tk interaction for you

Answer (score 0):

easygui is the easiest GUI python that I have used. Designs are prebuilt for you already. Examples of easygui can. be found here https://pypi.org/project/easygui/

 You can also use Flask where the frontend will be the web browser.

Comment: Unfortunate discovery: `easygui` requires `tkinter`, otherwise it will crash with `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'global_state'`.

Answer (score 0):

Tcl/Tk is an external library although it comes as part of the standard python install and it is an  external library. you can use other framework to do that .
Fundamentally, Python can’t talk to any GUI system without an external module. Since the most fundamental GUI libraries on any platform are usually C-based, that requires, at minimum, importing a library like ctypes which itself is minimal and allows you to load system GUI libraries (in dlls or delis, depending on your platform).It is possible, in theory at least, to drive a GUI solely from ctypes, but it’s not very practical .